# Conexão Mysql não aparece no Data Connection

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio

Atualizei meu Visual Studio pra versão 2017 e estou tentando conectar a um banco de dados MySQL através do Entity Framework.

O que acontece é que não aparece a opção para conexão no MySQL:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparece apenas SQL Server.

Já instalei o Connector/Net através do próprio instalador que baixei no site do MySQL.

Instalei também esses três pacotes:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode estar errado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possivelmente [faltou um plugin](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/visualstudio/). Ele também está no MySQL Installer:

[image: MySQL for Visual Studio]

Comment: oi, realmente eu não instalei ele, mas no meu mysql installer ele aparece indisponível para instalação.

Comment: agora que percebi que ele só fica disponível para versões anteriores (antes de 2015). o que posso fazer?

Comment: [Esperar um pouco](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,653594,656428#msg-656428) ou trabalhar com o VS2015 por enquanto.